# Gradle liquibase plugin incremental build issue

Tags: gradle, liquibase, incremental-build

I am using the [liquibase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin) plugin.
I want it to participate in incremental builds, so I defined:

```
tasks.withType(org.liquibase.gradle.LiquibaseTask) {
//for incremental builds
outputs.dirs("$rootDir/liquibase/src/main/resources", 'build/generated')
}
```

Everything works fine, except that after I do a `./gradlew clean` (which deletes the `build/generated` directory), the task is still considered `UP-TO-DATE`, so it doesn't execute again the migrations.

Full context of the issue: I am using the [docker avast plugin](https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin), I am spinning up a PostgreSQL database, I run the liquibase update (db is empty, so all the migrations should run), then I use [jooq codegen](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ) to generate Java classes based on the schema (they are generated in `build/generated`). The other tasks (`composeUp`, `generateJooq`) have the same `outputs.dirs` gradle configuration, but after I execute  `./gradlew clean` they are re-executed.

Comment: [Build scans](https://scans.gradle.com/) or info logging should tell you why Gradle considers the task up-to-date, please add that information as it will help figuring things out.

Comment: I also reached out to Vincent Mayers, the Director of Community Operations at Gradle, since this question has more to do with their product than Liquibase, and he said that if you send him an email, he can invite you to their community slack to get help, too.  vmayers@gradle.com is the address.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I think the issue was that all tasks were using the same outputs.dirs. I fixed it by creating a dummy file in each task, define it as an output file and use that as an input for the next task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a dummy file in each task, define it as an output file and use that as an input for the next task.